# kdump configuration partition creation

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

During kdump configuration do we need to create a partition manually or will it get created automatically when adding in /`etc/kdump.conf`  (eg: `ext3 /dev/sda4`)

```
# cat /etc/kdump.conf 
ext3 /dev/sda4
```

With the above setting, Will the device `/dev/sda4` get mounted by the crash (capture) kernel automatically.

Comment: Probably better on SuperUser SE.

Answer (score 0):

The partition specified will not be created automatically, it will need to exist and be mountable with the mount program using the specified file system type. From the [kdump.conf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/kdump.conf):

```
Options
    <fs type> <partition>
        Will mount -t <fs type> <partition> /mnt and copy /proc/vmcore to /mnt/var/crash/%DATE/. NOTE: <partition> can be a device node, label or uuid.
```